# Load assemblies into new app domain and forward page requests to that domain

Tags: .net, asp.net, appdomain

I want to know if it is possible to forward all page requests within a sub directory of an ASP.NET web application to a new application domain.  This way I can dynamically load assemblies and new pages without dropping them into the BIN directory of the web application and potentially taking down the entire web app.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a subforlder (in your IIS) configured to be an independent application, there will be a different app domain for the execution, different web.config and so on... if you navigate to another page of the same application, everything will run and be loaded in the same app domain.

This to my knowledge is the default behavior of IIS.

Comment: It is possible to override the default behavior of IIS and forward pages to a specific app domain?